# Show that the following inequality involving polynomials holds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

Suppose $x_1 + x_2 = x$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive integers. Let $c$ denote a positive real value that does not equal 1, I'm interested in showing the following inequality:

$$x^2 + 14cx_1^2 + 14cx_2^2 + x^2c^2 > 36x_1x_2c$$

My attempt:

Since $x = x_1 + x_2$, expanding the expression, we have

\begin{align*}
x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2 + 14cx_1^2 + 14cx_2^2 + (x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2)c^2 > 36x_1x_2c
\end{align*}

I'm trying to see if there are any like-terms that I can combine here. But I don't see anything that would be helpful here.

Comment: It is not true in general.. just try plotting it on Desmos and it breaks for some values of $c$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan could you give me an example of $c, x_1, x_2$ for which this breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because by AM-GM $$x^2+14cx_1^2+14cx_2^2+c^2x^2=(1+c^2)(x_1+x_2)^2+14c(x_1^2+x_2^2)\geq$$
$$\geq2c\cdot4x_1x_2+14c\cdot2x_1x_2=36cx_1x_2.$$
The equality occurs for $c=1$ and $x_1=x_2$ and since it's given $c\neq1$, the equality does not occur.

Comment: Right, I know that the quality occurs when $c = 1$. My question is asking about the validity of the inequality, not equality.

Comment: @Adrian See please better my post. I proved your inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding $x^2$ is not that useful in this case. If you simply leave $x^2$ as it is and factor it, then you would obtain this expression:
$$
 14cx^{2}_{1} -36x_{1}x_{2}c + 14cx^{2}_{2} + x^2(1+c^{2}) > 0
$$
Now factor out $14c$ and apply Binomial theorem.

Edit: typo

Comment: Could you give more details on how I would apply the Binomial theorem here?

Comment: I just edited my answer. You need to factor out $14c$. Try again then. Also I was assuming that $c$ would be positive. As someone mentioned before the original statement does not hold for all $c$. If you factor correctly you will also see why

Comment: So factoring out $14c$ gives me $14c(x_1^2 - 2.57x_1x_2 + x_2^2) + x^2(1+c^2) > 0$, are you saying I can apply the Binomial theorem to $x_1^2 - 2.57x_1x_2 + x_2^2$? I don't see how that term can factor?

Comment: Oh sorry, for some reason I thought 36/14 = 2. The inequality does not hold in general, since the expression reduces to: $(1+14c+c^2)x^2-0.57 x_1 x_2 >0$. This is not true in general.

Comment: I honestly don't see how the expression reduces to $(1 + 14c + c^2)*x^2 - 0.57x_1x_2$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mess. See Micheal Rosenberg's answer